# Deno: Print bitmap on ESC/POS printer

Tags: typescript, printing, deno, escpos

I'm currently trying to print out a bitmap with my ESC/POS printer. For this I followed [this](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=274) documentation.

How to connect to the printer I already figured out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75444292/deno-send-ansi-print-instruction-to-esc-pos-printer).

But now I have the problem that when I try to send a special instruction to the printer it just prints the instruction as ASCII string and does not interpret it.

The code I am currently using looks like this:

```js
// connect to printer
const connection = await Deno.connect( {transport: 'tcp', hostname: '<PRINTER IP>', port: 9100} );

// read in file
const file = await Deno.readFile( './ticket.txt' );

// send file to printer
await connection.write( file );

// close connection
connection.close();
```

The `ticket.txt` file looks like this (It is the same as on the [EPSON example page](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=274).):

```
ESC "@"
GS "(L" 139   7  48  67  48   "G1"   1 128   0 120   0  49

0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x0C 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x3C 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x7C 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x81 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x83 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0x87 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x87 0xFD 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0x00 0x78 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x87 0xF1 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x3E 0x00 0x1F 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x83 0xE7 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x5C 0x00 0x0F 0xC0 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x4F 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x4E 0x00 0x07 0xE0 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x7F 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x4F 0x00 0x01 0xF0 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x3F 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x87 0x80 0x01 0xF8 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x3F 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x83 0x80 0x00 0xFC 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x1F 0xC8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x81 0xC0 0x00 0x7E 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x1F 0x98 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0xC0 0x00 0x3F 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x0E 0x3C 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x60 0x00 0x3F 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x0C 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x1F 0x80 0x01
0x80 0x05 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x0C 0x00 0x1F 0x80 0x01
0x80 0x07 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFF 0x80 0x01

0x80 0x03 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0xFF 0x80 0x01
0x80 0x03 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xFF 0x80 0x01
0x80 0x01 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x1F 0x80 0x01
0x80 0x01 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x80 0x7F 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xC0 0x00 0xFF 0x01 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0xFA 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x7F 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x7F 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x1C 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x3F 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFC 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x3F 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xF8 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xF8 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xF0 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x07 0xFF 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFF 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x07 0xFF 0xFF 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x07 0xFF 0xFF 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0xFF 0xFF 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0xFF 0xFF 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0xFF 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFE 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFC 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xF8 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xF1 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xE3 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0xC3 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFF 0x02 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xFC 0x06 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x0E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0xE0 0x04 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x0E 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0x00 0x0C 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x1C 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x1C 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x38 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x38 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x38 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0xF0 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x70 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x01 0xE0 0x02 0x00 0x00 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x07 0xC0 0x01 0x00 0x00 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x1F 0x80 0x01 0x00 0x01 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x02 0x00 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x01 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x00 0x01 0x03 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x03 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x01 0x0F 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x58 0x03 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x67 0x07 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x63 0xC7 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x7C 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x73 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x78 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x73 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x3B 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x3B 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1B 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x9C 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x70 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x00 0x3F 0xFF 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x03 0xFF 0xFF 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04 0x3F 0xFF 0xFF 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x03 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F 0xFF 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01

0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F 0xFF 0xF8 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x3F 0xFF 0xE0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x1F 0xFF 0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0F 0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07 0xF0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF

GS "(L"   6   0  48  69  "G1"   1 1
GS "V" 66 0
```

If I send the whole now to the printer then it prints me the entire thing only as text out.

What do I have to change so that the printer interprets the text as instruction?

Thanks! ~Mqx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample data described on that page [EPSON example page](https://www.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=274) is assumed to be processed by this tool [Send Data Tool](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5027&scat=47&pcat=3), converted to ESC/POS commands, and printed.

You have several options.

- Create a program that converts the sample text data into ESC/POS commands based on the specifications described on these pages [Commands in Code Order](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=72), etc., and process it before sending.
- Similarly, based on the specifications, manually convert the sample text data into binary data for ESC/POS commands and send it.
  By the way, you can create a sample text file converted to binary data file with the above tool. [Send Data Tool](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5027&scat=47&pcat=3)
- Use some existing library, create sample data according to the specifications of the library, and send it from the library.

Comment: I have tried the 2nd thing, but it did not work. The printer printed only black lines. I assume that I have sent the data incorrectly.

Comment: If the printer you are using is ITPP047 in the previous question, it seems that the specification of the printer you presented does not support bitmap printing commands starting with `GS "(L"`. Please rewrite to other bitmap printing commands and data written in the specifications.